# Is there any way to change the "Load UI" setting based on what file you're opening?

Tags: interface, settings

When opening one of my own files, I of course want Blender to load the UI exactly how it was when I last saved the file. But when opening files from other sources, I do NOT want to load their insane UI decisions. Why would I want the entire UI to change to whatever crazy default the file's author thought made sense (and lose my own personalization in the process)?

I know you can change this setting globally in edit-->preferences-->save/load ... but I don't *want* to set it globally. Because, as mentioned above, what I want depends on which file I'm opening.

And I know you can choose whether to load UI when using the file-->open menu in Blender ... but I don't *want* to do it that way every time because the built-in file browser is clunky and much slower than just dragging in a file.

Ideally, Blender would recognize that files saved by me should be opened one way, and files saved by others should be opened the other way. Either just by recognizing the fingerprint on the file or perhaps by setting it up based on which folder the file was found in. (For instance, .blend files from my 'Downloads' folder should never load UI.)

Failing that, maybe there could be some addon that forces a "Load UI? Yes/No" choice EVERY time a file is loaded?

This just seems like *such* a pain, and there *must* be a better way...

Comment: Ther isn't to my knowledge but you could try suggesting it on  [Right-Click Select](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/?sorting=hot) and see what reaction you get.

Comment: There is nothing like that right now and I voted to close this question as being too localized and probably not applicable for a lot of users. Because honestly, many users just create their own files, or append objects from other files. Or at least nobody is constantly switching between opening own and other people's files so that they cannot decide which setting they want as default. And when I open downloaded files from here for example I intentionally keep the UI settings from the file, because this sometimes helps troubleshooting.

Comment: Hi :). I'd welcome such option as well, as there isn't one afaik. Right-Click Select is a good place to start though :)